# How to stack several videos using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I have four cameras that are recording videos and wand to stack all videos into one video file. The final video must be a 2x2 grid.

[image: final video - 2x2 grid]

THE HARD PART is that sometimes cameras are not recording simultaneously.

Here you can see **one situation** of how cameras are recording:

```
Camera 1 timeline: |recording....................................|
Camera 2 timeline: |stopped....|recording........................|
Camera 3 timeline: |recording.........|stopped....|recording.....|
Camera 4 timeline: |recording..................|stopped..........|
```

Explanation:

- Camera 1 is recording all time.
- Camera 2 is starting recording later.
- Camera 3 is recording, then stopped a period of time, then again recording.
- Camera 4 is recording a period of time, then stopped.

In the final video I want to synchronize each video by timestamps.

If a camera is stopped a period of time then at its position must be a black portion.

How can I do this?

Comment: **(1)** Are you doing this on command line or via a programming language? **(2)** If by code, can you run FFmpeg as an external `Process`? Also can you step frame-by-frame thru video timeline? The idea is that you create a bitmap (of video tiles or black area) and send to FFmpeg process to encode as a new frame. **(3)** On command line you'll have to prepare the individual videos (create required duration black videos as "stopped" to join `concat` with "recording" videos where needed. Then use all 4 videos as input with mosaic filter.

Comment: @VC.One After many time I am back to this problem. I am running ffmpeg as an external process. On recording I set for each input these filters: `-use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1` and `-copyts`. In this case I have timestamps equal to `Clock time`. I can add a black frame at the end of each video to have black screen when cameras are stopped. But **(1)** how to combine videos to create final video and **(2)** how to synchronise audio?